# Are there two contradictory definitions of the limit of a function at a point?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I have found two different definitions of the limit of a function ***f*** at a point ***a*** in very popular calculus/analysis texts.

In one, the function ***f*** is asked to be defined on an open interval containing the point ***a***, possibly excluding said point (*Stewart, Wade*).

The other definition, more popular in analysis books, simply asks that point ***a*** be a limit point (also called a cluster point) of the domain of the function (*Bartle and Sherbert, Abbott*).

In both cases the epsilon-delta condition is requested.  In the first definition, for the limit to exist it is necessary that *x* can *tend* to ***a*** from both sides, that is, with values greater and less than ***a***.

In the second version, since any extreme of an interval is also a limit point, ***x*** is not required to tend to ***a*** on both sides.  The latter also implies that the sided limits are particular cases of the general definition.

Furthermore, the theorem which is usually stated as "*There exists the limit of **f** at a point **a** and is equal to **L** if and only if both sided limits exist and are equal to **L***" only makes sense in that case for interior points of the domain.

My question is: Which of the two definitions is correct or, in any case, more rigorous?  Are they equivalent and am I missing something?
Any clarification on this is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I must say that I learnt a different definition than the official one mentioned in wikipedia. But if we can assume that the function is defined in a neighborhood of the point , the limit exists iff the limits from left and right both exist and coincide.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, these are indeed two different definitions of the limit of a function at a point. In my experience, your observations can be generalized: most introductory textbooks use the first definition (where the function is required to be defined in a punctured neighborhood of the point, and thus in particular one-sided limits must be defined separately), while most advanced books use the second definition (where the domain of the function is less constrained).

In and of itself, a definition cannot be correct/incorrect—a definition is just giving a shorthand name to a longer mathematical statement. And both definitions are stated rigorously and can be used self-consistently when developing examples and further theory. So the real question is: why does this difference exist?

The idea of limit points/cluster points belongs to topology. Even in the case of subsets of the real line, it requires some time and effort to define limit points and teach students how to understand and work with them. Furthermore, when studying fundamental calculus there isn't much other role that limit points play—that only makes much sense in the context of more general topological spaces.

So textbooks for fundamental calculus (for typical first-year university courses, say, which will be taken by all kinds of science students) tend to avoid the notion of limit points altogether, and work with the definition where the function is assumed to be defined everywhere on both sides of the point in question. That suffices for nearly all practical purposes and is easier to teach and learn.

More advanced textbooks (aimed at people who will be taking further math courses, and who in many cases will have already taken a typical first-year calculus course) often choose the more flexible definition using limit points, because the extra investment will pay off when analysis on more general or abstract spaces is discussed.

Comment: Very well explained especially the paragraph which tells that a definition can't be correct / incorrect. +1

Comment: I think you have completely clarify my doubt. My main concern was that both definitions were equivalent and not seeing why. Thank you very much for answering.

Answer (score 2):

The first definition is specific to functions defined on subsets of $\Bbb R$. The second definition is more general and applies to functions on any [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space). The definitions agree in all cases where the first definition's domain requirement is met, i.e. $f$ is defined in an open neighborhood of $a$ (possibly excluding $a$).

The only way they can disagree is when the second definition gives a limit but the first definition refuses to give one because $f$ is "not defined on enough of $\Bbb R$ near $a$". In these cases, $f$ can be extended to a larger domain in such a way that the first definition gives the same limit.